# Exactly N in a line

Tags: code-golf, combinatorics, grid, restricted-time

Given a number N from 2 to 8, place any nonzero number of queens on a grid of any size so that every queen has exactly N queens (counting itself) in each of its row, column, and each diagonal.

**This challenge has a significant [restricted-time](/questions/tagged/restricted-time) runtime limit.** Your code must finish all N from 2 to 8 (combined) within the 60-second timeout on [TIO](https://tio.run/#). This makes brute force unlikely to work.

Some example outputs are below. You can use this [verification script](https://tio.run/##fVXfa@NGEH62/orBeYh8URTbzXGcqR9KoXAv0VEKfRDCbKSxvURaqbsrO@7Rvz2dmZVsJ4UKLO1@@83vmXV38vvWLN9u9t53bvXw4LwqX9oD2m3dHtOybR7Uw@Pnxy/zxXwZVbiFHfpNpdWuNap28c7qKgGLh/VvtMXZKgLQWwZWwGdrfuWr1f2ioJNKNwtYQ41GBGcBWl5B@bxg1KLvrdkwQod5XsC2tbABbeDVKrPDWFTdBfF7WMxYPXNse/zAEp/CYdnW7w@Xw@E7iznruGNykaquQ1PFI1zkjF48vBaLohv4vywuHj8vv379Mpcsuq7WflNr52Pt0arnGhM47tHi4NGZRKexKssEiNcMnPU1kx9KOR/Deh0IlxN@SHwMJBfnw4NUsP8Qc6rUSGaVF/oQMXGiq63Fqi8xHl0VN4dwqGzF7E03XWs9uJPjBP26x/KF3VWkyVp1gnYLi1sn5fmrRzSOjiqYDxA2nT9Bg@gd@D1SUUylvW6NkzRShvX2FIumBAxlZCLrDdbYoCGhNTj0seubgUQJmBHJOSSn3nMTmH4zB1VTz53F9eBmOj0LLc7gteQvEkzTOw97dUBQnnpa0a41GAIjFdHkBr6rCnzLgTiqPklz7@/8HrQDq3Y7rKJJo143hJLztIob1cW0S4JRcV@M0WCETqWhgU8Qj1L3Mk10NJtdj4QIFeQD7Tkvso8m1NB9Yxj4W3fxp2CDWDzjbpGAfHlE8/eTP@ScJn2wgge2kss9kMAftseCrdXaIGsXqzJVYu4uKF6Mi2U0oSI5CbnjeiUgkhTt0GlDHd0Mfl7DjzmV@x/pqNYcpJZXDZXehi7Kbqk05Js/ttBS@9ANsFdWlaFRDZXhWmo@SFE7SnN5uiZcrTxuWMrF/N4MYQuynqbZlHtu8DDPBU61qfBV6CE1vOLc8AVyXZGLwoIj@R2pNdiBzrYlutDw2nS9j8Yk5rxInbdUqqCbAdZF80V4pU1qSY3wiUGDxssiCm705kW4l8tHiNS@EsYTWaCsxEKUm/jcaQFarIpo0lniwFMyDt/HNIUOSuBp9nYDf1q6D@DU9twgrq95jFvwSIOhXEi9o3ixxAoreD6x3qOmacBXKlN9kvF5rhU5Pkb6jP5I4wSoyn3QVCqHKSXw25Ytgao5BadhDuG7/MUBh3vfbu/56z6UOxG5kpqhdyhpn4bgprDtTcn3DXUpeRk8IgaNtzY0vqpK35ZRmmVpGtEvG98BiX6KaMdLfghMecm/KBtXQTAsg3hYpVmUjnRWGL6p4GeY8cDPhD@gWcCzYPBf) to confirm your outputs.

*N=2*

```
.OO.
O..O
O..O
.OO.
```

*N=3* (by Christian Sievers)

```
..OOO......
.O.O...O...
OO...O.....
O...O....O.
O......O..O
..O...O..O.
..O..O....O
.O...O..O..
.......OO.O
...O..O..O.
....O.O.O..
```

*N=4* (by Christian Sievers)

```
...OO..OO...
..OO....OO..
.O...OO...O.
OO........OO
O....OO....O
..O.O..O.O..
..O.O..O.O..
O....OO....O
OO........OO
.O...OO...O.
..OO....OO..
...OO..OO...
```

Your output grid can be square or rectangular. It may have empty rows and/or columns, even ones on the outside as a "margin" that makes the array bigger than necessary.

You can output as a 2D array of two distinct values of your choice, or as a string that displays as such.

For the 60-second time limit, running verification code doesn't have to happen within this time. If your language is not on TIO, you test it on any reasonable machine. On the off chance that your grids might be so big that TIO can't print them, it's allowed to run the test with storing all 7 grids instead of printing them, such as to a size-7 list where that any of them may be retrieved.

Comment: Great challenge! I've tried to run the verification script on some of my shorter output but I get an error message (not true or false.)

Comment: @LevelRiverSt Is it one of the assertions, or something else? What's the output? Do you have the format mentioned in the footer?

Comment: @LevelRiverSt Oh, oops, my verification code is assuming the grids are square. Let me fix this.

Comment: Ok, I thought it might be that. Anyway, I've added a TIO link for the verification to my answer, so you can check if there is anything else I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @LevelRiverSt I updated the snippet, I think it should work now.

Comment: Verified Up to 5 now. That's the biggest output TIO will run without truncating. I guess you didn't expect output this big! Thanks again for the challenge.

Comment: @LevelRiverSt Yeah, I expected huge outputs but not quite this huge. Do you think it would be reasonable to require that each of the grids in the submissions is stored to a variable within the time limit during the test even if it can't be printed?

Comment: Cardboard Box's answer runs in about 11 seconds and mine runs way faster than that. So it wouldn't invalidate any existing answers, so yes, I think it would be reasonable. The idea for this type of output was Cardboard box's, they deserve the credit, I just improved on the idea slightly. I doubt the outputs will get any bigger. The interesting question now is if anyone can come up with a different soluton that gives shorter output with reasonably short code.

Comment: Wow, I think the awesome answers help understand why some existance proofs in math involve unnecessaryly huge numbers. I have a nice solution for N=4 that I wouldn't like to stay unknown: `...OO..OO.../..OO....OO../.O...OO...O./OO........OO/O....OO....O/..O.O..O.O../..O.O..O.O../O....OO....O/OO........OO/.O...OO...O./..OO....OO../...OO..OO.../`

Comment: @ChristianSievers That's a beautiful solution, and vaguely reminiscent of an example on wikipedia for the recent question about 3 in a row. If you have code to produce solutions like this, I personally think you should post it. There will be sticklers that say you should only post competitive golf answers, but in cases like this I disagree.

Comment: @LevelRiverSt My program is also not competitive wrt time, and not very interesting. It's just some integer linear programming: one 0-1 variable for each possible queen on a grid point, and one for each line indicating that this line has no queens. One constraint for each line: sum of queens on this line plus N times the this-line-has-no-queens-variable equals N. And don't forget: at least one queen!

Answer (score 11):

## Python 2, <sub><strike>141</strike></sub> 138 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVXBkuI2ED2jr@jsHGyDYTBFdjNUfMimKqk97RxSuTguSoMFiLVlR5JZyNZ@@6RbsrGZyiUn5O7X3a/7tURztcdarV7ZA@zqRooC9rqu4Cy03Msdt7JWYHZaNpaxh6O1jdk8PhrLd19qxOzL@utiV1eP/HH94/rDMlmuWCH2cBB2W0h@qBUvTXjQsojhpbQaUvhDtyLaMIBCVvhZCuX8EVq4MUJb7xg82TInpxa21WpLFgzLshz2tQZbW16CVHDRXB1EuILpkBLmkEQ5xhJS119HuBvGUfGIXV3@ByLDwLyHAci9a2Qz5kMQmFF8vuBNI1ThI8ngw7tgURqxocM4mMrOwacIqXfH@i4R5XDZhkGMU6Ay8OtR7L4QO66Aa82vUO8hCYzr7O9WCGXQVcCyM4mqsVeohLAG7FEgeVVIUts4AZ3@19BlikFh@xN33opSVEJhUApG2NC0VQfKcEgI8hLeY2N490mdeYnK3cJlR3Px7haU3IzjyF9cM1VrLBz5WQC3KDDHr1oJ3ximYJMHeOYFrgM1YqSxGE2LcLBHkAY0PxxEwSYVv2zRiuTxFFa8IZljX9TRd8VwvbwcuHq4T2EfNXerha4oGq@UC8qRA37TXNw3m6BebaXI8I9swqmvgSi6FyaJwf2uqNj9belmrsW5qyLOVCX7DZ0idvcnp2qlVIKyu6pu@1y5mU@c9IcVm6BIxrXckF4xuEjsttukTkcTwc8pfFui3N8Zk1VToyayjs3VMGaFsdsdN76iv2oxPGE/tZYHicS3xhaSJov4hTvfuerWDj78YDcYmmW9@HjFEp8@h8FfKlicaqmcOsbqeCgdoURDhvs4ZCIuYucUGkVMgyB4ValUTWsR85xmq5@WOXNPB041S07xU7xenubrZfx@fZq9X@eb5/RbM5NT66Yvafa@YRWRoSHD83emU2/98LSKWKOlsll2mV2nyYn8LvbiYnM6Xv3xFekw1is39LLAFcAL0oowWpimlNbN4U23b8bJGN19ypOxSZYFtBgBlfEX3F0x3A1EI7lDnzYOorxf3s5FQKLUQ/IYMkSxCcHI0QMMw71zrULw5/gPQgvTltZsAj/Y2D3SGESLP4gRgyPcPaU@j427l8b/R9joVuB3wv6vjKqtMNPWMca/D169FJza3ATdRtGtzuQsyekhxN5DGc2CDQQ42QAH8xmC3EPy/K32/cWfJ5F/zKlwP78Uhq3NRiz8433KoziYz@cfRUnvhfEjRdiL0Fh75picZkmER8IhCXpV@9g0XXo2p3s27t8L6eCTP4b/kC6B1L@ZsF0yRuOhj86jPgbr678)

```
n=input()
P=[280]
for t in[1j,9,40j-40,64j+64]:P={p+i*t for i in range(n)for p in P}
r=range(792)
print[[x+y*1jin P for x in r]for y in r]
```

Takes `n` as input and prints a list of lists of booleans.

While the grids are generated within the 60 second time limit, they are larger than TIO's 128KiB limit, so they were simplified to be printable via TIO thanks to math junkie.

I added in the verification script to the TIO link so it can also be verified within TIO.

Here's my attempt at drawing my original solution for n=3. Hopefully this helps visualize it. Replace 57 with 40 and 408 with 64 for the current solution.

[image: hand_drawn_solution]

Comment: Looking at the TIO output for `n=3`, I'm not sure this works, though the output I'm looking at is cut off. What is supposed it supposed to look like? I see 3 queens in the first 3 rows in the same columns, which seems like will cause a problem with the short diagonal of the first queen, as there aren't any queens in the displayed rows after, and the cut off rows seem too late to be in that diagonal. (Edit: `n=2` seems to have the same issue.)

Comment: I've attempted to simplify the printed output to better show the shape of the grid: Each of the `xyz:` headings show the character number of that `O` on the current line. The `--- ... ---` headings are meant to show the line number after a bunch of empty lines. I've edited it into your post since the TIO link is too long to be a comment

Comment: Nice solution! I'm curious where you got the constants from. Do they give the smallest displacements to always avoid unwanted sharing of lines?

Comment: @xnor Yeah I just found them through brute force. I originally used `[1j, n, n**2*(1+1j), n**3*(1-1j)]` but changed them to constants to save bytes.

Answer (score 9):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>85</s> 77 bytes

```ruby
->n{j=n**3+n
((0...n*n).map{|i|((?.*n*n+?O)*9)[~i%n+i/n*n,j]}+[?.*j]*j)*n*$/}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vOss2T0vLWDuPS0PDQE9PL08rT1MvN7GguiazRkPDXk8LKKBt76@pZakZXZepmqedqQ8U0cmKrdWOBspmxWplaQLVqOjX/jfSKy0oydew0Kyuya0pKC0pVkiLzo2t/Q8A)

Similar to and inspired by cardboard_box's answer, but rotated by 45 degrees.

Below are the first 16 lines of the output for `n=4`. It should be apparent that that within each 16x16 box, the queens form diagonal lines of 4. In between the boxes there is a single blank column. If this was not there, the diagonal lines of each `n**2` x `n**2` box would line up exactly with its neighbour when `n` is even.

There are clearly 4 queens on each horizontal row and 1 queen in each vertical column (except the blank ones.) The rest of the pattern is a repeat of the below, interspersed with `n**3+n` rows of blanks to ensure the diagonals do not clash (I could get away with just a few rows less, but the code is shorter this way.)

The output is truncated by TIO so it's only possible to get full output up to 5, but it's apparent from the way the pattern is constructed that it meets the rules. Output has been verified up to 5.

```ruby
.............O................O................O................O...
..............O................O................O................O..
...............O................O................O................O.
................O................O................O................O
.........O................O................O................O.......
..........O................O................O................O......
...........O................O................O................O.....
............O................O................O................O....
.....O................O................O................O...........
......O................O................O................O..........
.......O................O................O................O.........
........O................O................O................O........
.O................O................O................O...............
..O................O................O................O..............
...O................O................O................O.............
....O................O................O................O............

...many blank rows, then repeat the above a total of 4 times...
```

Comment: How is this so fast?! For `n=20`, the computation takes about 1 second even though the array has size `1,313,852,399`.

Comment: @xnor I was a little shocked by how fast it is as well. But see what it does: A) generate an array of `20**2=400` strings `20**3+20=8020` elements long, similar to the block for `n=4` shown above. B) generate a string of 8020 periods, and make an array of 8020 pointers to this string. C) take the whole thing, and make 20 copies of all the pointers. D) join the array elements into a string with the operation `*$/` (where `$/` is a special variable preinitialized to newline) and return the combined string. Only in step D do we have to handle the `20*(400+8020)` lines of `8020` characters.

Comment: @xnor To show that we work at the pointer level until the very end, try the following program. You will find every identical line in the output is modified with an X at the begining. `n=4;j=n**3+n;s=((0...n*n).map{|i|((?.*n*n+?O)*9)[~i%n+i/n*n,j]}+[?.*j]*j)*n;s[17][0]=?x;puts s*$/` Note that comments have additional control characters inserted in them at end of line so if you copy and paste code from comments you have to remove the formatting before running.

Comment: also the code as written doesn't produce the correct result for `n>8`. The constant `9` needs to be at least `n+1`, but this can be fixed for 1 or 2 more bytes; for arbitary sized n use `-~n`. The question specifically asked up to `n=8` so I left it like this.